Docker cannot run apache and nginx services at the same time on custom domain
First of all, thank you for your valuable answers, I am sharing the docker-compose.yml code with you; I don't have much docker knowledge but I need help because I need to use docker in this project.
I need to use ports 80 in apache and nginx at the same time, because when I put it in production mode I need to be able to access it from all domains and there will be a total of 3 domains (2 of them are subdomains)
docker-compose.yml:
version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    image: php:apache
    volumes:
      - "./frontend:/var/www/html"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - domain-net
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: domain.io

  member-frontend:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - "./member-frontend:/usr/share/nginx/html"
      - "./nginx/member.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - domain-net
      - nginx-proxy
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: member.domain.io

  backend:
    image: php:apache
    volumes:
      - "./backend:/var/www/html/backend"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - domain-net
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: api.domain.io

networks:
  domain-net:
  nginx-proxy:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy

I successfully stand up the service with the "docker-compose up -d" command, no errors, but I can't access the files.
and most importantly, it should call nginx on the member domain, but it fetches it as apache. I will be waiting for your comments and solutions, thank you (:
It redirected all services to the same apache service when I expected it to work correctly.

Guess you can bind a different IP to each web service as following page suggested https://serverfault.com/a/508325
Or, if you cannot bind different IP to each web service, think you can build a proxy in front of all services routing the traffic to the corresponding service, like a Nginx or Apache service listening all traffic from IP:8081 and configure it to make the corresponding redirect.
Hope it helps

I don't know how to set up the proxy so that 8081 redirects all services to 80. Can you explain it to me?

I mean to create an Nginx as an instance that receives all internet traffic, and then configure this Nginx instance to redirect the traffic according to your needs
